# C++ Можно ли задать функцию класса таким образом, чтобы наследуясь в подкласс, она меняла свой тип на тип подкласса

Tags: c++, классы

```cpp
    class Set{
        public:  
            //returns union of two sets
            friend Set operator |(Set set1, Set set2){ 
                //bla-bla-bla
            return set1;
            }
    };  

    class Ring::Set{
    };
```

И я уже не могу использовать оператор | для двух колец, чтобы создать третье, потому что no viable conversion from 'Set' to 'Ring'.

Обязательно переопределять для нового класса? Код будет идентичный, только вместо Set Ring.

Answer (score 2):

Для начала я бы написал не `Ring::Set`, а `Ring: public Set`, ну и передавал бы в оператор параметры не по значению, а по ссылке...

Далее, как вы понимаете, вы возвращаете `Set`. В общем случае `Ring` может иметь что-то дополнительное... Но если вы *точно знаете, что делаете* - добавьте конструктор `Ring(const Set&)`, и вопросов не будет - он будет преобразовывать полученный вами `Set` в `Ring`.

```
class Set{
public:
    //returns union of two sets
    friend Set operator |(Set set1, Set set2){
        //bla-bla-bla
        return set1;
    }
};

class Ring:public Set{
public:
    Ring(){}
    Ring(const Set& ){}
};

int main()
{
    Ring r1, r2, r;
    r = r1|r2;
}
```

Этот код вполне корректно [компилируется](https://ideone.com/9sqHGB).